# Laravel, What choose Multi Auth? Guards or Roles?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have always chosen method Role. In this project, which I would like to do, there will be about 5 registration methods and in each registration the fields will change. And each type of registration can be called a role, it will have its own ORM structure. and another html. I tried to find the answer in Google and found 2 options (WITH ROLES OR GUARDS). I would like to hear advice from experienced developers which option is better? Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your approach guard will be helpfull. because

- You can set any column as an identifier.
- You can use your different guard on different route.
- You can use your guard in stateful ans stateless environment.